How do I save Excel Macro files created from "New" Button in Document Set into SharePoint
I have a libary in SharePoint with Document Sets. Inside of the document sets I allow for a custom content type based of "document". In the template for this custom content type I have a macro'd excel file. My problem is this. Normally, if going into one of the document set folders, and I select something from the dropdown menu, it opens in the browser and saves into the document set. When I select the custom content type that is a .xlsm file (macro), it opens in excel. When I try to save it, it just shows all the common areas - it doesn't show the document set I am in. I don't want to have to search for that manually in the explorer. What, if any, settings can I change to ensure that when I am in a document set, and I go to the "new" dropdown and pick that content type that has the macro'd template - it saves into the document set I am in.
